# rm: cannot remove ‘stock/δ╓¼2\036y3~.«¡Φ’: Read-only file system( from usb)

Tags: filesystems, usb, rm

I am trying to remove a folder from USB. I tried to change the folder permission, its giving same error.

```
`sudo chmod 777 stock/`

chmod: changing permissions of ‘stock/’: Read-only file system
```

Also I did remount usb in r/w mode.

```
`sudo mount -o remount, rw /media/kannan/KANNAN/`

`rm -rf stock`

rm: cannot remove ‘stock/╖ï y▀á}▀.sß÷’: Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove ‘stock/\\êα╖Γì╩ö.║\036è’: Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove ‘stock/'≤H.'║H╚.\036ΘH’: Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove ‘stock/pbr²\tñ@å.ç8▒’: Read-only file system
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be some problem in the filesystem. check and repair the filesystem by

> dosfsck -a /dev/sd{xn}

then again do remove action.